# When logging in after session time-out, redirect to original page?

Tags: redirect

Wondering if there's any configuration or tricks to "redirect" a user to the record/page they were working when logging back in after the system boots them off?

For example. I'm working on contact record x. I go to lunch, only to find the system has logged me out. I log back in. Bam, I'm back at the contact record x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have `Force logout on session timeout` unchecked in Setup - Security Controls - Session Settings (and also `Disable session timeout warning popup` enabled and `Logout URL` not set - blank), but I think Force logout deactivation should be enough.

The only side effect is that users might (and they probably do) try to edit the record or save it after the session expired and are being asked to reenter the password and start over.